# Convergence radius of the product strictly bigger than the minimum.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Given two complex series $f(z) := \sum z^n$ and $g(z) := 1 - z$, is it true and if so, how can we show that the absolute convergence radius of their Cauchy product $r(fg)$ is **strictly** bigger than the $\min\{r(f), r(g)\}$?

The absolute convergence radius $r(f)$ must be 1 while the convergence radius $r(g)$ must be infinity because the sum is well-defined regardless of the value of $z$.

I just can't see why their product must have the radius strictly bigger than the above $\min$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can compute the coefficients of the cauchy product explicitly:
since $f(z) = \sum a_k z^k$ where $a_k = 1$ for all $k=0, 1, 2, ...$
and $g(z) = \sum b_k z^k$ where $b_0 = 1, b_1 = -1$ and $b_k = 0$ for $k \ge 2$, their Cauchy product will have the expansion:
$\sum c_k z^k$ where the $c_k$ are given by $c_k = \sum_{i+j=k} a_i*b_j$.

Plugging in our values for the  $b_j$ and evaluating the sum, we get exactly:
$c_0 = a_0 b_0 = 1$ and $c_k = a_0*b_1 + a_1*b_0 = 1-1=0$ for $k \geq 1$ because $b_j$ is zero for $j \geq 2$

Thus, we conclude that the cauchy product is actually the series:
$ f*g (z) = 1 + 0z + 0z^2 + ...$
which in turn obviously converges for all values of $z$.